# using -> to access a virtual function from an array of objects indices

Tags: c++

I am currently coding a c++ assignment focusing on the properties of inheritance.

There is a base **class gun {}**, and several derived classes:

**handgun: public gun {}**

**revolver: public handgun{}**

**pistol: public handgun{}**

As per the current assignment, I have added a **virtual** function **print()** to each of these classes that overrides the previous class's **print()**, adding its unique variables to be printed. For example, gun has **string manufacturer**, handgun has **string grips**, and pistol has **bool semiauto**.

Now, my professor wants me to make an array containing 2(two) objects, one object of type **revolver: public handgun** and one object of type **pistol: public handgun**.

In the assignment, he says we MUST use this exact code to print out the contents of the array:

```
for(int i=0; i <= numGuns; i++)
       **gunCabinet[i]->print();**
```

Now, for my code. The error in question is in bold, right near the bottom.

```
int main() {
//declares the revolver and pistol objects
revolver Anaconda;
pistol M9;

//sets appropriate variables for the objects
Anaconda.setManufacturer("Smith & Wesson");
M9.setManufacturer("Beretta");
Anaconda.setCaliber(".44 special");
M9.setCaliber("9x19mm Parabellum");
Anaconda.setGrips("Hogue grips");
M9.setGrips("U.S. Military specification grips");
Anaconda.setSights("6x scope");
M9.setSights("U.S. Military specification iron sights");
Anaconda.setLaser(true);
M9.setLaser(false);
Anaconda.setSingleAction(true);
Anaconda.setNumberOfRounds(6);
M9.setSemiAuto(true);

 int numGuns = 2;

 gun* gunCabinet;
 gunCabinet = new gun[numGuns];
 gunCabinet[0] = Anaconda;
 gunCabinet[1] = M9;

 // *(gunCabinet) = Anaconda;
 //*(gunCabinet + 1) = M9;



//gun * gunCabinet[/*numGuns*/2] = {&Anaconda, &M9};




for(int i=0; i <= numGuns; i++)
   **gunCabinet[i]->print(); //ERROR ON THIS LINE**

//cout << Anaconda << endl;
//Anaconda.print();
//cout << M9 << endl;
//M9.print();


return 0;
}
```

I have commented out my other attempts at making this work.

Now, when I run this, I get an error saying "base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘gun’".

Unless my professor made a mistake, I assume it is all me on this one. The problem is, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am not necessarily looking for an answer to my homework, rather, is his code valid? And if it is valid, can I have some pointers (no pun intended) on what I am doing wrong? thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your professor a member of the NRA by any chance? :-)

Answer (score 2):

you're creating the `gunCabinet` as an array of `gun` objects, but what you really want is an array of `gun*` (`gun` pointers).

```
gun* gunCabinet[2];
gunCabinet[0] = &Anaconda;
gunCabinet[1] = &M9;
```

Comment: Wow, I have heard great things about this website, but never used it before. You (and everyone) have been extremely helpful with an embarassing question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `->`, you need to invoke from a pointer type. When you use an array access, you are dereferencing one pointer, hence your error of it being a non-pointer type.

What you need to do is have a `gun **gunCabinet`, and initialize the array with the addresses of each of the stack variables, and then you can use the arrow operator on an array access.

```
gun** gunCabinet;
gunCabinet = new gun*[numGuns];
gunCabinet[0] = &Anaconda;
gunCabinet[1] = &M9;
```

Then you can use

```
gunCabinet[0]->print();
```

later on.

Answer (score 0):

The **->** operator is used with pointers, to access methods and members. A pointer needs to get the address of an object.

So, because you have an array of actual objects, and not an array of pointers, you need to get a reference to their address.
You can get the address of an object (unless the operator is overloaded) with the **&** operator.

```
gun = &gunCabinet[1];
gun->A_Guns_method();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but... The line in the `for` loop that the instructor gave is `**gunCabinet[i]->print();**` (at least as you quote it).  In your loop, you've written `**gunCabinet[i]->print();`.  I rather suspect that both the `**` before and the ones after the expression are there for emphasis, and are not meant to be part of the actual code.  (The ones after can't be.)  And without them, just making an array of pointers, as Platinum Azure suggests, is sufficient.  And necessary, regardless of the expression you use to access them, since arrays can't hold polymorphic objects; if you try to put something with a derived type into an array of base, it will be sliced, and all you'll get is a copy of the base part.  (More generally, assignment doesn't work well with polymorphism, and I generally recommend making base classes uncopiable, by deriving from `boost::noncopyable`.)

Comment: The **s were my attempt at making the statement appear in bold lettering through StackOverFlow's posting system. They are not part of the code, my bad.